# Customview autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, custom-view

[image]

In customview (red view) add constraint height = 45;
add customview to a view (subview of testviewcontroller, (green view)). add constraint hight=45 for subview. Run in iphone 5 ok, but run iphone 6 height of subview scale. Help me.Thanks!

Comment: You need to set auto layout for your red view when you add it to your green view.

Comment: thank you. because in objective-C not need to do this.

Comment: @Eric D http://prntscr.com/b9r5ql
I add by link class of viewcustom. i think don't need add more constraint